# Email widget: How to show inbox instead of subfolder?

Tags: email, app-widgets

I have a question regarding email on my Nexus 7 3G:

When I try to add an email widget on my home screen I'm asked to choose a folder, but I only have the option to select a sub folder in my inbox, not my actual inbox.

How can I let the widget show my complete inbox instead of a sub folder only?

Comment: I just tried on my Nexus 7, and "Inbox" was one of the options, mixed in with the other folders.  I wonder if the discrepancy is due to your email server -- mine is an Exchange server, and my email account is using the Exchange protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try to scroll down the list to find the inbox.  I think it is listed below, but it seems missing at first. I could not see it at first. But after several tries, I got the list to scroll down to find the inbox.